# How to define a component as default value for a prop in React?

Tags: reactjs

How can I do something like this correctly in React?

```js
import Bar from './Bar.jsx'

const Foo = ({ icon = <Bar />}) => {
  // ...
}

export default Foo
```

Right now using `icon = <Bar />` will simple give parsing error.

Comment: Should it not be `({icon: <Bar />})`?

Comment: @EmilKarlsson No. `=` is correct approach. What kind of parsing error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Use capitalized `Icon` prop to be able to use it as a component:

```
const Bar = ({}) => {
  return <div>Bar</div>;
};

const Foo = ({ Icon = Bar }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Live](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-breeze-ymp7m?file=/src/App.js:24-163)

Answer (score 1):

Don't include the `<>`'s, just assign it however it's imported (so Bar in this case).

You'll need to make the icon prop have a capital I, then you can use `<Icon />` to call any component passed to it.

If Bar has any props, add them to Icon and they'll be passed through to Bar.

```
import Bar from './Bar.jsx'

const Foo = ({ Icon = Bar }) => {
  return (
    <Icon />
  )
}

export default Foo
```